# How to reliably check if a document variable is not empty in ConTeXt?

Tags: context

Consider the following MWE:

```
\startdocument[title=]
  \doifemptyvariableelse{document}{title}{True}{\documentvariable{title}}
  Test
\stopdocument
```

So basically I have a document with a title variable. Now I want to check if that variable is empty (`\doifemptyvariableelse`). Instead of simply outputting the right branch and exiting the current code gobbles the next two tokens, which feels wrong.

Is there some easy approach to check whether a document variable is empty that does not gobble following tokens?

Comment: @Marco Well, I usually consult `setup-en.pdf` to see the available commands and it does not list `\doifdocumentvariable`. The wiki also does not mention the new commands. Would you like to add an answer?

Comment: Done. I can't for sure say why `\doifemptyvariable` doesn't work in this case. It has something to do with how the argument is constructed, I believe. But I leave that part to the experts.

Comment: a) `\doifemptyvariableelse` doesn’t work because there is a bug (wrong number of arguments) for the `TRUE` case. b) The commands will be added to setup-en.pdf (If you miss a command in the document you can send a message to the ConTeXt mailing list or the author of the document).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\doifdocumentvariableelse` (defined in `file-job.mkvi`), which uses `\doifsomething`. Example:

```
\startdocument[title=]
  \doifdocumentvariableelse{title}{\documentvariable{title}}{False}

  %% is the same as:
  %% \doifsomethingelse{\documentvariable{title}}{\documentvariable{title}}{False}

  Test
\stopdocument
```